# Try Method in Debug Window

Tags: apex, api, json, list

this is my first post, I don't speak english...ok.

I will consume an API and I have this method:

```
public without sharing class BP_ExpiredProductsCtr {

public static id accID;

public static void manageProducts(List<BP_ExpiredProductsParser> exprod){ 
                 System.debug(' ---- iniciando ---- ' + exprod);
          Account iAccount=[SELECT Id,FinServ__SourceSystemId__c FROM Account WHERE Id=:accID LIMIT 1];

         List<BP_ExpiredProducts__c> lstobjproduct=new List<BP_ExpiredProducts__c>();

             for (BP_ExpiredProductsParser objParser : exprod){

             BP_ExpiredProducts__c objProd = new BP_ExpiredProducts__c();

             for (BP_ExpiredProductsParser.Product objexpproduct:objParser.product ) {

             objProd.BP_Type__c=objexpproduct.productDescription;
             objProd.BP_Document__c= objexpproduct.productNumber;
             }
             objProd.BP_ExpiredDays__c = objParser.expirationDays;
             objProd.BP_NationalCurrencyAmount__c = objParser.tradeAmount;
             objProd.BP_OriginCurrencyAmount__c = objParser.amount;
             objProd.CurrencyIsoCode = objParser.currencyCode;
             objProd.BP_RelatedAccount__c=iAccount.Id;

             lstobjproduct.add(objProd);

         insert lstobjproduct;

        System.debug('AQUI ESTOY: '+lstobjproduct);
         }
         }
     }
```

And need try it in debug anonnymous.

The Json it comes like this:

```
 [
      {
          "product": {
             "productNumber": "0000000001",
              "productDescription": "PRODUCTDESCRIPTION"
          },
          "expirationDays": 400,
          "amount": 1000000.00,
          "tradeAmount": 1704500.00,
          "currencyCode": "USD"
       },
        {
          "product": {
             "productNumber": "0000000002",
              "productDescription": "PRODUCTDESCRIPTION2"
          },
          "expirationDays": 800,
          "amount": 2000000.00,
          "tradeAmount": 1805600.00,
          "currencyCode": "PEN"  },
... 
]
```

and the Parser class:

```
public class BP_ExpiredProductsParser {

    public List<Product> product;
    public Decimal expirationDays;
    public Decimal amount;
    public Decimal tradeAmount;
    public String currencyCode;

    public class Product{
        public String productNumber;
        public String productDescription;
    }
}
```

I try it with this:

```
BP_ExpiredProductsParser objproductparser=new BP_ExpiredProductsParser();

        objproductparser.expirationDays=11;
        objproductparser.amount=12;
        objproductparser.tradeAmount=12.3;
        objproductparser.currencyCode='USD';
        //lstobjproductparser.product = ;
        System.debug(objproductparser);

List<BP_ExpiredProductsParser.product> lstproduct1=new List<BP_ExpiredProductsParser.product>();

            lstproduct1[0].productNumber();
            lstproduct1[0].productDescription();

            lstproduct1[1].productNumber();
            lstproduct1[1].productDescription();


           objproductparser.product.add(lstproduct1);
            System.debug(lstproduct1);
```

But,appears the next message:

Line 12, Column: 28
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void productNumber() from the type BP_ExpiredProductsParser.Product

the line 12 is: lstproduct1[0].productNumber();

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This `productNumber()` is the syntax for invoking a method but `productNumber` is a class property so instead reference it like this:

```
lstproduct1[0].productNumber
```

though it is unclear what you are trying to do with that value. You could log it like this:

```
System.debug(lstproduct1[0].productNumber);
```

Comment: Hi, the correct code would be like this: lstproduct[0].productNumber='Example1';

I tried your code, but the debug returned the message: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: I tried your code, but the debug returned the message: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

The line of error point to: System.debug(lstproduct1[0].productNumber);